# kotlin collections converting a Map to a new Map with values calculated from the original

Tags: collections, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and i'm trying to summarize a query. 
I have a `Map<Int, List<Objects>>` with Int: Month and `List<Objects>` all the operations processes in that month.

What i'm trying to do now is to get a `Map<Int, Long>` in which Long: the count() of all the operations.

I already went through map, mapValues, fold... but without getting the correct answer.

Comment: isn't `mapValues` exactly what you want? Sure enough it gives you `Entry` instead of just value, but that is only one method call longer than ideal.

Comment: You should show code you tried and why it failed, because you actually mentioned a working solution so you must have been almost there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you start with:

```
val monthOfOperations: Map<Int, List<Operation>>
```

Then you can simply:

```
val monthOfOperationCounts = monthOfOperations.mapValues { it.value.size }
// result:  Map<Int, Int> of Month to Count of Operations
```

Note the result is `Map<Int, Int>` since the collection size is `Int` and not `Long`.  To have a `Long` if really required:

```
val monthOfOperationCounts = monthOfOperations.mapValues { it.value.size.toLong() }
// result:  Map<Int, Long> of Month to Count of Operations
```

But there is no reason to store an `Int` value in a `Long`.

Comment: ok, silly me...i just didn't put it.value.size inside mapValue. Thanks!