# Kotlin how convert map with long and Pair to other map?

Tags: kotlin, mapping

I have a construct like this:

```
     var values = mutableMapOf<Long, Pair<String, Boolean>>()
```

No I need to have one map from this above like this:

```
     val transformedMap = Map<Long, String>
```

I cannot transform this first to second. Andy suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kotlin collections converting a Map to a new Map with values calculated from the original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163830/kotlin-collections-converting-a-map-to-a-new-map-with-values-calculated-from-the)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of iterators will require a variable for storing the resulting map, but I think `associate` can do it directly:

```
values.entries.associate {
    it.key to it.value.first
}
```

The other options are like this

```
val output = mutableMapOf<Long, String>()

//values iterator, for, forEach, keys, etc
output[key] = values[key]?.first
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
val transformedMap = values.mapValues { it.value.first }
```

Comment: That will create a `List<String>`?

Comment: @cutiko no, it will make the `Map<Long, String>` that's asked

Comment: You are right, my apologies the function naming confused me: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html @wenus check this other option is more idiomatic